# Returning array of uninitialized classes

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to return an array of uninitialized classes from a function, and then procedurally initialize each one in turn?

Reason being is because each class is going to use the same data object, and I want each class to execute a function to modify the data in turn.

I could write it as;

```
const test = async () => {
    await new Class1(data).execute();
    await new Class2(data).execute();
    await new Class3(data).execute();
}
```

And it would work fine, but I'd like it to be cleaner.

Edit: 
Instead of test() initializing each class and then calling execute on each in turn, I would like to have a function that returns an array of classes. I can then loop through said array, initializing them in turn that way and calling execute. The reason for this and not the method above is because the classes that are going to call .execute() are going to be randomized each time.

Comment: What's an "uninitialized class"? What's not "clean" about what you have there? A class can be referenced like anything else, e.g., `const SomeClass = Class1; const c1 = new SomeClass();`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like it to look like? From what you are describing [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) could work but I'm struggling to justify it based on your example.

Comment: I've edited my post, I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: It feels like you want to use [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or maybe [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern. Perhaps as part of [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). It's hard to say, though.

Comment: So return an array of classes--I showed you how in the first comment.

Comment: @DaveNewton Initally, that's what I tried. My app thinks it's a function.Edit - Works anyway. Despite calling it a function. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomppa-FI I don't know what "my app thinks it's a function" means (and recall that JS has "classes" only in the sense of syntactic sugar).

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, outputting typeof class to console results in function: className. It threw me off at first - I didn't consider that it wouldn't pick it up, but I didn't think to try it regardless.

Comment: @Tomppa-FI Hence the reminder to remember that JS doesn't have classes.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yup, thanks.

Comment: @Tomppa-FI FWIW generators and the use of `yield` would allow you to do exactly what you are after too, without having to return an array. Just if that helps with the pattern you are after.